# What is the actual meaning of keyword "this"?

Tags: c++

I have two questions related to C++:

In many textbooks, the keyword `this` is a pointer to the **calling object**.  Correct?

As i like to play with coding, i wrote the following simple code:

```
struct Base
{
    void g();
    virtual void f();
};

void Base::f() {
    cout << "Base::f()" << endl;
}

void Base::g() {
    cout << "Base::g()" << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(*this) : " << sizeof(*this) << endl;
    this->f();
}

struct Derived : public Base
{
    int d;
    void f();
};

void Derived::f()
{
    cout << "Derived::f()" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Base a;
    Derived b;

    cout << "sizeof(a) : " << sizeof(a) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(b) : " << sizeof(b) << endl;

    a.g();
    b.g();
}
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
sizeof(a) : 4
sizeof(b) : 8
Base::g()
sizeof(*this) : 4
Base::f()
Base::g()
sizeof(*this) : 4   // why 4 bytes not 8 bytes?????????
Derived::f()
```

If `this` is pointing to the calling object, should the second line of `sizeof(*this)` print 8 instead of 4 since the calling object is `b`?  What actually is happening here? Is `this` has been demoted?!!!!

If `this` has been demoted to type `Base`, how `this->f()` invokes the correct function? I am really confused.

Comment: Try adding a call to sizeof(*this) in Derived::f().  See what that puts out.  The call in Base::g() doesn't know that it's part of a subclass.  In that case, *this legitimately references Base, not Derived.

Comment: and how do you expect `sizeof(*this)` be evaluated at compile-time? It's no different than `sizeof(Base)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
void Base::g() {
    cout << "Base::g()" << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(*this) : " << sizeof(*this) << endl;
    this->f();
}
```

The important distinction that needs to be made is that `sizeof` is a **compile-time** operator, not a **runtime operator**. The compiler interprets the expression `sizeof(*this)` as "the size of the object pointed to by `this`", which, in the scope of `Base::g` would be an object of type `Base`. The compiler will essentially rewrite that statement as this, because it knows that the size of `Base` is four bytes:

```
cout << "sizeof(*this) : " << 4 << endl;
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. I modified the code to print the value of `this` instead of `sizeof(*this)` and i compare it with &b and &a.  The answer matched my expectation.  Umhhh.. Thanksssssssssss.

Answer (score 1):

`Base` can't see/access/know about anything that's part of derived objects, so `sizeof` only reports the part of the object that is visible to it.  More to the point, `sizeof` in a method of `Base` can't know that there are or will be subclasses (you can subclass `Base` without recompiling it, after all) so it can't report on anything but the part it knows about.  (`sizeof` is computed at compile time, not run time.)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a constant value pointer to the object that the function is a non-static member of. Which means that, for `this` to be a viable value, it must be used only in non-static members of a class. Remember: you must use an object instance to call a non-static member function (instance.function or instance->function); `this` is a pointer to "instance".

The reason the size is never the 8 that you expect is because `g` is a member of the class `Base`. For `g`, `this` is of type `Base *const`, and therefore `*this` is of type `Base&`. The `sizeof(Base)` is 4. Even if it were a virtual member, this would not change; the type for that implementation of `g` would always be `Base *const`. Virtually overridden versions would have different types, but only the type of the class that implements them.

`this`'s type does not follow polymorphism; it has exactly and *only* the type that the function was defined with.

Comment: Even if `g` were virtual it wouldn't matter because `g` is never overridden by the derived class, non?

Comment: Just to clarify: Even if `g` was virtual, `sizeof(*this)` would always be be 4 in `Base::g()` regardless of whterh it was called via a derived type (for example if the virtual `g()` wasn't overridden). I know that this is what you say in your last sentence, but the second paragraph might leave readers thinking that `sizeof(*this)` would 'follow' the derived type even in the base implementation of `g()`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct function `f` is called because `Base::f` is virtual. This tells the compiler that when a call to `Base*->f()` is requested, the actual address of the callee is looked up in the vtable of the actual object whose member you invoke.

The **type** of the `this` in question is `Base*`, which is why `sizeof(*this) == sizeof(Base)`, but its vtable belongs to a derived object and hence the function call to `f` goes to the override.